# What is "crypt key missing" error in Pgadmin4 and how to resolve it?

Tags: pgadmin-4, docker-desktop

I am using pgadmin version 6.1. I am trying to connect to my postgres db hosted in docker with pgadmin on my local machine.

I used the below command to get the docker container ip address:
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id

Answer (score 355):

When starting Pgadmin4, did you set a "master" password or just bypass that prompt?  I just ran into the same thing and restarted setting the "master" password and was able to continue without that error.

[image]

Comment: Had the same problem, but when resetting the "master" password the "Crypt key missing" error was gone!

Comment: UI fail indeed.

Comment: This was fixed in pgAdmin 6.8
https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/6960

Comment: Version 6.8 (4280.88) - bug still there

Comment: Bug still there, 6.9

Comment: v6.10, bug still here

Comment: v6.11 bug _still_ there

Comment: v6.12 bug still there

Comment: v6.13 bug still there

Comment: v6.15 bug still there

Comment: 2023 bug still there

Comment: v6.18 bug still there. Did anyone tell them? Checking...

Comment: I think there is no issue for this on https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues ... I found two similar ones (can't login to redmine), but they're long closed.

Comment: Just created a new ticket on their board: https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5735

Comment: v6.20 bug still there

Answer (score 7):

Set Master password.
This worked for pgadmin4-6.15 in windows

Comment: I looks like this answer already exists

Answer (score 2):

After installing the server, I just had to restart my machine to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

master password has to be set first then you will be able to register a new ser with login and password

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this happening, when I skip entering the master password but try adding the new server. I restarted it and entered the master password and it worked.