# Pgadmin internal server error "crypt key is missing"

Tags: postgresql, docker, fastapi

I am using pgadmin 4. I am trying to connect to my postgres db hosted in docker with pgadmin on my localmachine.

This is the error:
internal server error "crypt key is missing"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hf0m.png)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/70010673/11895568

Comment: how is this related to fastapi?

Comment: set the master password....